# How to pass constructor parameters in a 2D array?

Tags: c++, arrays

So I've just come to C++ from Java and was wondering how you would pass parameters into a constructor for a 2D array. Example, I've got a class called square which draws a square and I have a 2D array of squares, but my constructor takes an x and a y so how would I go about pass these parameters into the 2D array?

```
// Main.cpp
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

#include "Square.h"

Square grid[10][10];

int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow renderWindow(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Chess 2.0");            

while (renderWindow.isOpen())                                                       
{
    sf::Event evnt;
    while (renderWindow.pollEvent(evnt))
    {
        if (evnt.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        {
            renderWindow.close();
        }
    }
    renderWindow.clear(sf::Color::White);
    /// RENDER HERE

    for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0;j < 10;j++)
        {
            // Init 2D array here
        }
    }
    renderWindow.display();
}

return 0;
}

// Square class
Square::Square(float x, float y)
{
    sf::RectangleShape rectangle(sf::Vector2f(100, 100));
    rectangle.setPosition(x, y);
}
```

Comment: The short answer is: You cannot do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to do this. For some reason C++ treats multidimensional arrays differently, so this would yield an error:

```
    void func(int param[][]) {}
```

While this wouldn't:

```
   void func(int param[][1]) {}
```

A solution would be to use a vector:

```
   #include <vector>
   vector<vector<Square>> grid;
```

You can use vectors the same as arrays, but to add items you use name.pushback(object);
You might also want to make the Square constructor private and have a static function that checks how many instances there are using name.size() before creating a new instance. It's a tough workaround, but it works.

Comment: In case you don't know what static functions are, you can make use of them by putting the word static in front of a public member function. You can then call it by using Classname::StaticFunctionname().